# laravel throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException for validation

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to create a form with post method. When there was validation in the method, I faced with "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException" , but when i deleted validation it worked correctly. I don't know why!

HTML

```
@if(count($errors)>0)
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li style="color: #cc5200;"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
    <form method="post" action="{{route('test.added')}}">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="grade" value="{{$grade}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="course" value="{{$course}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="numbers" value="{{$numbers}}">
        @for($i=0;$i<$numbers;$i++)
            <div>
                <span style="color: #cc5200">question{{$i+1}} :</span>
                <textarea name="question[]" rows="2" style="width: 50vw">{{old('question')[$i]}}</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <div class="ml-1 mr-2">
                    <span>1-</span>
                    <input type="text" name="firstOption[]" style="width: 10vw" value="{{old('firstOption')[$i]}}">
                    <input type="radio" name="trueOption[{{$i}}]" value="1">
                </div>
                <div class="ml-1 mr-2">
                    <span>2-</span>
                    <input type="text" name="secondOption[]" style="width: 10vw" value="{{old('secondOption')[$i]}}">
                    <input type="radio" name="trueOption[{{$i}}]" value="2">
                </div>
                <div class="ml-1 mr-2">
                    <span>3-</span>
                    <input type="text" name="thirdOption[]" style="width: 10vw" value="{{old('thirdOption')[$i]}}">
                    <input type="radio" name="trueOption[{{$i}}]" value="3">
                </div>
                <div class="ml-1 mr-2">
                    <span>4-</span>
                    <input type="text" name="forthOption[]" style="width: 10vw" value="{{old('forthOption')[$i]}}">
                    <input type="radio" name="trueOption[{{$i}}]" value="4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        @endfor
        <input type="submit" value="ok" style="float: left;color: white;background: #cc5200">
    </form>
```

web.php

Route::post('/td-admin/test/add-finalStage','TestController@added')->name('test.added');

TestController

```
public function added(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'question.*'=>'required',
        'firstOption.*'=>'required',
        'secondOption.*'=>'required',
        'thirdOption.*'=>'required',
        'forthOption.*'=>'required',
        'trueOption.*'=>'required',
    ]);
    Test::create(  ...
```

It made me crazy. please help me.

Comment: your code looks correct. Show your `added` method complete

Comment: sorry,it's too long (more than 2500 chars)